# mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, check 2 columns at a time

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

Let's say there are 4 columns in my table

```
ID int(11) AI PK
BANK_ID int(11)
BANK_BRANCH_CODE varchar(255)
BANK_BRANCH_NAME varchar(255)
```

I want to UPDATE the `BANK_BRANCH_NAME` if the combination of `BANK_ID and BANK_BRANCH_CODE` already exist or else INSERT new data.

Here's what I got

```
INSERT INTO bank_table (BANK_ID, BANK_BRANCH_CODE, BANK_BRANCH_NAME) VALUES 
(bankId, bankBranchCode, bankBranchName) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE BANK_BRANCH_NAME = bankBranchName;
```

But it seems like it only keeps inserting new data.
Are there anything wrong with my query?

Comment: oh, something like `ALTER TABLE bank_table ADD CONSTRAINT unique_bank_branch UNIQUE (BANK_ID, BANK_BRANCH_CODE);` ?

Comment: It's working ;) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of `BANK_ID` and `BANK_BRANCH_CODE`. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works only when there is a unique constraint or primary key violation.

```sql
ALTER TABLE bank_table
ADD UNIQUE (BANK_ID, BANK_BRANCH_CODE);
# other queries...
```

***[DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8dRa8Vzipe5oSLB5fGM7BT/4)***

Comment: Note that this will not work when bank_id or bank_branch_code are null.

Comment: @ysth thanks for pointing it out. You're right.